# Overlapping system and Rakarrack playbacks on a X-Fi Gamer soundcard (setting up guitar)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, soundcard, jack

I've gone through installick JACK and Rakarrack. I then had the problem with other audio (like YT flash videos or music player) disappearing when I turn on JACK etc., I've just installed pulseaudio JACK module and it works. Now I have two other remaining issues:

1. I have no idea what should I connect or disconnect in JACK.
2. The system playback (that of microphone/input jack) is overlapping with Rakarrack's playback. Result is I can hear my unamplified electric guitar AND the modified playback from Rakarrack (that is much quieter, by the way).

I can hear unamplified sound regardless of turning on JACK and/or Rakarrack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Stop jackd when you don't use it using **qjackctl** graphical interface : just click "stop" to exit jackd
2. To mute the direct mic/line input  sound you ear, run **alsamixer** in a terminal .
   Use arrow left/right  keys to select "mic" or "line" fader,  then use down arrow key to lower the volume (or <kbd>M</kbd> to mute).
   This will not affect the recorded sound level.
   You may also install and use **gnome-alsamixer** gui which is easier than **alsamixer**.